# Como buscar una string en un nodo con valor T

Tags: c#, árboles-binarios

Necesito buscar una string en un nodo generico en el cual tengo como TAD una clase

```
public class InfoIndice 
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Linea { get; set; }
    public int Existencia { get; set; }       
}
```

este es el dato contenido en el nodo

```
public class Nodo<T>
{
    public Nodo<T> Izquierda { get; set; }
    public Nodo<T> Derecha { get; set; }
    public T Valor { get; set; }
    public string Llave { get; set; }
}
```

este es el nodo, lo que no encuentro es como buscar en el nodo cuando me dan un Nombre y me dijeron que recorriera el arbol y fuera comparando con cada uno de los nodos si contenia el string pero estos no tienen el Contains y el compareto no sirve para encontrar la string contenida en un nodo de InfoIndice

Comment: Que usas un `List<T>` para guardar los nodos? O a donde los tenes que buscar..?

Comment: Es un arbol binario